# Remove keys with empty or null values in qs.stringify when constructing query params in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm constructing a URL with query string parsing `qs.stringify` in which I want only non-empty or non-null values to be present in the URL.

The result I am getting is below:

```
localhost:3000/user?name=john&age=
```

But, I don't want the `age` param to be included in the url as the value for age is `null`.

Below is an excerpt from my code:

```
const url = `/user?${qs.stringify({ name, age })}`;
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a function using `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` to filter out non-null and non-empty values:

```js
function filterNonNull(obj) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v));
}

const url = `/user?${qs.stringify(filterNonNull({ name, age }))}`;
```

Comment: this removes 0 as well

Answer (score 4):

`qs` package added `skipNulls` option since [v5.1.0](https://github.com/ljharb/qs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#510)

> To completely skip rendering keys with `null` values, use the `skipNulls` flag:

```js
var nullsSkipped = qs.stringify({ a: 'b', c: null}, { skipNulls: true });
assert.equal(nullsSkipped, 'a=b');
```

Don't worry, the `qs` package supports skip `undefined` values as well.

```js
console.log(qs.stringify({a: 1, b: undefined}))
// => "a=1"
```

[runkit](https://runkit.com/embed/ky02h8lmcwzz)

But `qs` does NOT support omitting the below zero values: `0`, `''`

```js
var qs = require("qs")
console.log(qs.stringify({a:1,b:''})) // "a=1&b="
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove nullish values in `filter` option of `qs.stringify` via fallback to undefined for nullish values:

```js
const values = qs.stringify({a: 1, b: ''}, { filter: (prefix, value) => value || undefined });
assert.equal(values, 'a=1'); // true
```

Comment: that's a nice direction, but it will exclude 0 as well

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
const url = `/user?${qs.stringify(Object.entries(obj).forEach( item => ((item[1] === null) || (item[1] === undefined ) ? delete obj[item[0]] : item));)}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use reg exp
``` const url = ``/user?${qs.stringify({ name, age })}``.replace(/[^=&]+=(&|$)/g,"").replace(/&$/,"") ```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow only those properties which are not null;
Easiest way to do that is below

```js
const name=null,age=23;
const obj = {
name,
age}
let newObj = {
}
for (prop in obj){
if(obj[prop]){
newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
}
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const params = {
  a: 1, 
  b: '', 
  c: '', 
  d: 4, 
  e: undefined, 
  f: null
}
queryString.stringify(params, {
  skipEmptyString: true,
  skipNull: true
})

//=> 'a=1&d=4'
```